# How to save array values using PDO

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I am new to programming and I have a problem when storing the values ​​in an array using PDO.

I get a string from a form input:

```
  $brands = "Nike, Adidas, Reebok";
```

I get an array where the string separated by commas:

```
$pieces = explode(",", $brands);
```

I need to store each value in the array in different records within a table using PDO, something like this:

```
$statement = " INSERT INTO userbrands (Name, Email, Brand) VALUES (:name, :email, :brand)";
$sth = $db ->prepare($statement);
$sth -> execute(array(':name'=>$name, ':email'=>$email, ':brand'=>$pieces));
```

Thanks for answering a rookie question!

Comment: Use a for loop to iterate over the `$pieces` array.

Comment: Take note that the values will be `Nike`, `[SPACE]Adidas` and `[SPACE]Reebok`. To use `explode` and ignore whitespace, either loop through and use `trim`, or use `preg_split('/,\s*/', $brands)` instead.

Comment: You're right @h2ooooooo I will work on that, many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$statement = " INSERT INTO userbrands (Name, Email, Brand) VALUES (:name, :email, :brand)";
$sth = $db ->prepare($statement);
foreach ($pieces as $one_piece) {
  $sth -> execute(array(':name'=>$name, ':email'=>$email, ':brand'=>$one_piece));
}
```